# How to Start Activity From Service Android Q

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

Hi Developers I hope All are You fine. I need help. I make a AppLocker app and I use service to check which app i currently running. i locked app in my database with package name. When I show my lock screen From Service my Intent hit but lockScreen not Showing.How i call Activity From Service below is my Codeto start Activty from Service

```
if (locker_list!=null) {
                            if (launchapp) {
                                Log.d("TAG", "run: lock Screen Show");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Lock_app_screen.class);
                                intent.putExtra("package_name", current_app);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app is running in the background. These restrictions help minimize interruptions for the user and keep the user more in control of what's shown on their screen.
for more...
[see this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)